# How do I stop Visual Studio Making so many files for .NET core projects

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2010, build

I'm moving all my projects to .NET Core applications but have noticed my Visual Studio project folders are now enormous!

The folder structure looks like this:

[image]

All that is fine, but the bin and obj folders are enormous and with much "duplication" I realise it is not true duplication because there are the debug and release versions of things.

In `obj > Release > netcoreapp3.1` there is `PubTemp > Out` which seems to include another version of everything.

All these folders include `runtimes` and `wwwroot`. as far as I know the contents of these folders are the same every time. `wwwroot` contains only static files in this setup, because this particular website contains a lot of downloadable PDFs, I have about 100mbs of PDFs and the runtime files stored multiple times!

PDFs

1. Solution Root > wwwroot > downloads
2. Solution Root > Obj > Release > PubTemp > Out > wwwroot > downloads

RunTimes

1. Solution Root > bin > Release > netcoreapp3.1 > runtimes
2. Solution Root > bin > Debug > netcoreapp3.1 > runtimes
3. Solution Root > obj > Release > netcoreapp3.1 > PubTemp > Out > runtimes
4. Solution Root > obj > Debug > netcoreapp3.1 > PubTemp > Out > runtimes

Both the PDFs and the Runtimes are about 100mb, so I have 600mb where I really only need 200mb!

Similarly all the language packages that .NET installs and the NUGET packages, are all duplicated, when as I understand it, really, only my own libraries need to be compiled in DEBUG/Release versions...

Is there any way to make Visual Studio (2019) consolidate these unnecessarily duplicated files?